# Regex: delete all text except 'SS' followed by 4 to 8 characters

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a long text file that looks like this:

> Species:  Sorbus subcuneata |  Somerset Whitebeam Date: 2007-09-30
> England OSGR: SS7448
>
> Species:  Sorbus subcuneata |  Somerset Whitebeam Date: 2007-09-30
> England OSGR: SS7448
>
> Species:  Sorbus subcuneata |  Somerset Whitebeam Date: 2001-10-02
> England OSGR: SS74394901

I'd like to extract **only** the 'SS****' strings (some have 4 digits, some have 6, some have 8).

I have searched the forums here for various explanations of regex but they all seem to be much more complicated scenarios, and I'm too much of a noob to reverse-engineer them to do something simple like this.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: What do you mean by extract? Only the SS***** strings must remain, or do you want only want to find them?

Comment: I've found that https://regex101.com/ is quite useful when trying out regex patterns.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `\bSS(?:\d\d){2,4}\b`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b          # word boundary
SS          # literally SS
(?:         # non capture group
  \d\d        # 2 digits
){2,4}      # group may appear 2,3 or 4 times
\b          # word boundary
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

If you want to delete everything but `SS...`, use:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*?\b(SS(?:\d\d){2,4})\b.*$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it in Notepad++:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
- Set Search mode to Regular expression
- Find what : `\bSS(\d){4,8}$`
- Click Mark All
- Click Copy Marked Text
- Open a new text file
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the copied text.

[image]